# jQuery accordion doesn't drop like it's supposed to

Tags: html, jquery, css, accordion

I am currently building a website which contains a accordion menu.

My problem is the following, when I click the desired item which has to collapse it does collapse but it goes right back to uncollapsed after it collapsed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".set > a").on("click", function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(this).siblings('.content').slideUp(200);
            $(".set > a i").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
        }else{
            $(".set > a i").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
            $(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
            $(".set > a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $('.content').slideUp(200);
            $(this).siblings('.content').slideDown(200);
        }

    });
});
```

[Here is the code (jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/us8genrh/)

This code used to work perfectly fine, but for some reason it broke and doesn't work anymore.

I hope someone can help me out.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/us8genrh/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think somewhere along the lines you have swapped your accordion to start open (ie removed the styles that initially hide it) so the following lines in your `else` both opens and closes it:

```
    $('.content').slideUp(200);
    $(this).siblings('.content').slideDown(200);
```

If you are starting with your accordion open, then you need to start with the active class on your link:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".set > a").on("click", function() {
    var link = $(this);
    if (link.hasClass('active')) {
      link.next('.content').slideUp(200, function() {
        link.children('i').removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
        link.removeClass("active");
      });
    } else {
      link.next('.content').slideDown(200, function() {
        link.children('i').removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
        link.addClass("active");
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion-container">
  <div class="set">
    <a href="#" class="active">Vloeren <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
    <div class="content">
      <ul class="submenu">
        <li class="submenu-item">Witte vloer</li>
        <ul class="submenu-two">
          <li class="submenu-item">Witte vloer</li>
        </ul>
        <li class="submenu-item">Zwarte vloer</li>
        <li class="submenu-item">Grijze vloer</li>
        <li class="submenu-item">Paarse vloer</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also cleaned up your jQuery and fixed your `else`

Comment: Thank you Pete. It does work. (all the accordions are closed by default)

But if I now click on one of the other items it doesn't close the one that already is opened.

Comment: Fiddled around with the code you sent and now it does exactly what I want it to do!

Thanks a lot!

https://jsfiddle.net/n88pf62r/

if you're interested I made it like this, not sure if it's correct syntax but it does work like it's supposed to work now.

Comment: If you want the code to start off closed by default, all you needed to do was remove the active class I added and start the `.content` with `display:none`